# Playing Steam games on different versions of Windows from same location?

Tags: steam, windows

I have a dual boot with Window 7 (C:) and Windows 8 (D:). I have a few Call of Duty games on Steam that I want to be able to play on both OS.

Would it be possible to have the game installed on another drive (E:) and get Steam on both OS to point to this or would there be compatibility issues between Windows 7 and Windows 8?

It is just to save space as two installations is too much. I have tried this Origin and it works so I'm wondering would it be possible with Steam.

Comment: I love how C: (W7) looks like a smiley face, while D: (W8) looks like a distraught face.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's fine as far as the game files are concerned; I've done this with an external drive on two different PCs, and after upgrading PCs.

A problem does arise however when game saves are stored on the Windows partition; some games do this, some games don't. Steam Cloud games should be fine either way, but certain games might be looking in (Active Windows Drive)\Users\My Documents or something for saves, so you'll end up with 2 save files, one on each OS. If this is a problem you might want to look at making [junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx) so both game saves are accessed at the same location. Alternately, if the My Documents folder in particular is the problem, I think Windows lets you move the location of that without a junction, too.

Comment: You can move the My Documents folder by highlighting it, right-clicking, selecting Properties, Location tab, Move button.

Answer (score 0):

Between Windows 7 and 8, you shouldn't have any problem.

I updated my Windows 7 into 8 on C:, leaving my G: (where all my games are installed) alone, and didn't need any update.  I just reinstalled Steam, and everything went just fine.

Comment: That being, things would probably be different between Windows and OSX, for instance, or OSX and Ubuntu, so maybe the question's title would worth an edit.

Comment: I think the question talks about sharing games between dual boot installs, not OS upgrade.

Comment: My answer denotes that there's no difference in the games' files between Win 7 and Win 8 (no compatibility update required); therefore the files are compatibles with the two systems; therefore it will work with a dual boot involving these two OS.